# & breaks message string in thymeleaf with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

We have a spring boot project which consists of an API to send the notification emails which works fine. We do accept the email subject, body, title etc from the incoming request and set it into the mail template. When the body title do have "&" character it do breaks the message. For example,

If the incoming message is:

`Message for A&B` then in an email it do display as `Message for A` -> missing `&B` 
`Message for ABC` then in an email it do display as `Message for ABC` -> works fine

Here is the mail template that I am using

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" th:lang="${#locale.language}" lang="en">
<head>
  <title th:text="#{email.notification.title}">Failure Notification Alert</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<p>
  Dear Team,
</p>
<p> <span th:text="${notification.bodyTitle}"> </span> </p>

<table border="1" style="width:750px">
  <tr>
    <td><b>Message</b></td>
    <td><b>Occurred at</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr th:each="notification : ${notification.messages}">
    <td th:text="${notification.key}"></td>
    <td th:text="${notification.value}"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<p>
  <span>Regards, </span>
  <br/>
  <em>Team XYZ.</em>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Spring Boot: 2.6.6 
Java : 11

Comment: You state that you have an API that _accepts_ information. Is that a REST API? How is the data sent? Using POST? Or are you using GET and is the `&` seen as a query parameter separator?

Comment: You might need to encode `&` as `&amp;`.  (I think Thymeleaf should be doing this for you, but I'm not sure how you have it configured -- what does your Thymeleaf configuration look like for your email?)